# Is there a way to run OpenVPN client in the background?

Tags: openvpn

I use Ubuntu 18.04.1, however, for some reason my connections from network-manager-openvpn don't work properly at the moment.

Is there an easy way to start and end an OpenVPN client connection without keeping a terminal on during the connection? I would appreciate suggestions that I can use in a script.

---

**Edit: SOLUTION**

Submitting the job with nohup such as:

`$ sudo nohup openvpn vpnconfig.ovpn &`

and killing the job with PID or:

`$ sudo killall openvpn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have noticed using OpenVPN on Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, is that if you simply close the terminal, the tunnel will still stay established. As long as you don't press `Ctrl + c`, you can still use it. You may however, have to run the following in order to make the system use the tunnel:

```
sudo ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 dev tun0
sudo ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 dev tun0
```

To stop the tunnel, run:

```
sudo killall openvpn
```

Comment: Submitting the job with nohup and killing with killall solved the problem thanks!